# How to hide specific text on mobile in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

**I have this code:**

```
<div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 pt-6 gap-8">
    <div class="col-start-2 col-span-2">
        <h3 class="text-4xl pb-3">Text 1</h3>
        <p class="text-2xl">Text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I need to hide this whole div on mobile. I already tried the suggestion from this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/841

```
<div class="hidden md:block max-w-7xl mx-auto grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 pt-6 gap-8">
    <div class="col-start-2 col-span-2">
        <h3 class="text-4xl pb-3">Text 1</h3>
        <p class="text-2xl">Text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

but this hides nothing. I then tried the following code, by adding `invisible md:visible`

```
<div class="invisible md:visible max-w-7xl mx-auto grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 pt-6 gap-8">
    <div class="col-start-2 col-span-2">
        <h3 class="text-4xl pb-3">Text 1</h3>
        <p class="text-2xl">Text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this works, but it doesnt hide the div, as per specifictation this does not affect the layout rendering:
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

What would be the correct way to accomplish this in Tailwind CSS? Of course, I could add custom css to hide it on the small breakpoint, but I think this would not be the propper way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you're overwriting `hidden` with `grid` which is also a display utility. Your code should be:

```
<!-- remove grid after mx-auto -->
<div class="hidden md:block max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 pt-6 gap-8">
    <div class="col-start-2 col-span-2">
        <h3 class="text-4xl pb-3">Text 1</h3>
        <p class="text-2xl">Text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you were using an IDE or editor with Tailwind support you would get a warning when you have two classes that do the same thing. Personally I use VS Code with Tailwind CSS Intellisense, but there are plenty of other options, they will help you prevent small mistakes like this.

Comment: This code does not show the text at all for me?

Comment: Then you have a config issue. Share the contents of your `tailwind.config.js` the above code works fine in Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/CqT9wzVEww

Comment: Thanks for that link. I found that these issues were because of normalize.css of the default blade. I removed it and everything works correctly.